# List of lists help sorting

Tags: python

I have a list of lists (like a matrix). Suppose that I want to sort every list in that list of lists. As an example suppose the following list:

```
l = [[1, 3, 2, 4], [3, 5, 1, 6]]
```

now to sort it I do:

```
for li in l:
   li.sort()
```

The problem is that it segfaults... The python interpreter that I'm using is 3.4. The weirdest thing is that if I put a `print` inside that loop it will not segfault... The list of lists I'm using has a very big dimension (10^6 x 80), with all elements integers (I checked it with `all(((isinstance(item, int) for item in items) for items in l))`).

I have attempted to search the web with no luck. Does anyone have an idea or should I report it to Python bug tracker?

EDIT:
I think I have solved it. Once I suspected of pandas I decided to uninstall it and install it again with pip3.4. What scared me most wast the overwhelming amount of warnings that it generates. Still after compiling and install it, I tried to run the script again and no segfault appeared. Thanks

EDIT again:
Sorry to bother again guys the problem still persisted after a while, and it was bad RAM. The problem only showed up when python tried to use the bad memory address range. I guess everything has its lifetime, even lifetime warranty GSKILL memory. :)

Comment: What do you mean *"segfaults"*? Can you provide more information (error messages, etc.)? Obviously the example you have actually provided works perfectly.

Comment: Segmentation fault, memory violation, python crashes, etc. I enable the flag -X faulthandler and it points to the line of the sort.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using numpy or something like that?

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: Don't just list synonyms, *provide more information*! Platform? Distribution? Version (3.4.what)? Libraries? Is there any way you can make this reproducible?

Comment: How did you install Python 3.4? If you install a different Python 3.4, can you reproduce it? Is your Python 32-bit or 64-bit? If it's 32-bit and you have a 64-bit platform, can you reproduce it with a 64-bit Python?

Comment: Before anything else thank you for the answers...
Relating to the previous questions, 64 bit linux mint with 64 bit python. 

In an attempt to track down the bug and ensure it was not one of the modules, I have written the list of lists to disk,  reload it and do the sort and it doesn't segfault. So I now believe that this is something related with pandas (the only module that I'm using). However, for some reason when I invoke any print command it just puts everything on track... 
I will load the program under valgrind to see if I can get more information...